# Can I give a script elevated file access and run it from my current user?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, file-permissions, du

I have a script (I call it `dusort.sh`) I use to gauge which files are taking up the most space on my drive in a given folder. It essentially boils down to this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

du --all --human-readable --max-depth=1 $1 | sort -h -r
```

I need to run the command with `sudo` because otherwise `du` cannot read certain directories (`/`, docker volume directories, etc). Is there a way to make it so I can run this command without being prompted for my root user password every time I want to check file sizes?

I have tried changing the file ownership

```bsh
sudo chown root:root dusort.sh
```

but that doesnt seem to affect things. The only way to run this command without getting `Permission denied` warnings on files is like so:

```bsh
sudo ./dusort.sh
```

Comment: Like this?  [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13058)

Answer (score 0):

Woo! Ok I've got a working solution prompted by [lx07](https://superuser.com/users/269373/lx07). To get the solution I want, which is running a script with root permissions *without* typing `sudo` or inputting a password each time, there are two steps.

First, add these two lines to your `/etc/sudoers` file (edit with `sudo visudo`)

```
myusername ALL = (ALL) ALL
myusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/myscript.sh
```

Second, add an *alias* to `script.sh` prefixed with sudo. In my case, I added it to `~/.bash_aliases`

```bsh
alias myscript='sudo /path/to/myscript.sh'
```

now you can run the script as root without specifying sudo or giving a password!

```bsh
$ myscript
# it runs as root!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the /etc/sudoers file and append the following lines:

```
Cmnd_Alias     MONITORING=/usr/bin/du  
your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:MONITORING
```

if you are not the only one that will use the scripts, create a group containting whe users and replace the last line for:
%group_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:MONITORING

This way you won't be required for a password every time you execute the script

If you already have sudo powers just append the sudo in you script:

```
sudo du --all --human-readable --max-depth=1 $1 | sort -h -r
```